# Content sent through jQuery ajax is getting cut off

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I am trying to send html via jQuery's $.ajax() method, and then dump the html into a new .html file, but the content is getting cut off for some reason.

I have set up a test case:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
      var contents = $('html').html();
      var filename = "test/000.html";
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/file.php",
         data: "content="+contents+"&fn="+filename, 
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(msg, ts, xh){
             console.log(msg);
             console.log(ts);
             console.log(xh);
             alert("success");
         },
         processData: false,
         error: function(X, textStatus, error){
             alert("Error saving... please try again now.")
         }
     });
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div id="rteContainer" class="dev">
  <div id="textEditor">
    <form>
    <textarea name="balh" id="balh" rows="25" cols="103"></textarea> 
    <input type="button" id="updateContent" value="Update Changes">
    <input type="button" id="closeEditor" value="Close Without Saving">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the file.php file is:

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/html;charset:UTF-8");
$content = "<html>".stripslashes(urldecode($_POST["content"]))."</html>";
$dump_file = $_POST["fn"];
$fp = fopen($dump_file, 'w');
fclose($fp);
echo $content;
?>
```

Why is is getting cut off? I'm guessing it's come encoding problem, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Can you give an example of the response your getting and where it's getting cut off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The html string, `contents`, has to be url-encoded before you `POST` it. Javascript provides the `escape()` function, just for this purpose.

Pass `$('html').html()` to `escape()` and assign it to `contents`, like so:

```
var contents = escape($('html').html());
```

Comment: This answer of yours solved my problem in seconds!! I was scratching my head for half a day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your script is dying of embarrassment at the massive security hole in it.

Never, ever, write into a file where the filename is a form parameter without validating the filename first.  Even a novice hacker could use this script to overwrite any file on your system that the webserver has access to.

In your Ajax call, pass a `{ }` style array of key value pairs in the `data` parameter, don't concatenate the variables with ampersands yourself:

```
data: { content: contents,
        fn: filename }
```

Oh, and you're never actually writing the content into the dumpfile, so whatever file 'fn' points at will just get truncated.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't thinking security when I wrote it, because it's going to be password protected when it's done. I'm not sure what you mean that I'm never actually writing to the dump file. Are you saying that the existing content gets overwritten by the new content?

Comment: I mean that you `fopen` the dump file, and then close it straight away.  You don't store `$content` (see `fwrite`) in the file.  But please fix the security problem first or someone will use your script to overwrite itself.

Comment: Also, FWIW, if you correctly pass `contents` as shown above I don't _think_ you need to escape it, but you should remove the `processData` flag from the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the ampersand in the javascript is causing a problem.  Try replacing it with '&' and see if that fixes it.